# Windows authentication using AD group in Asp.net WebApi not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have a developed a Restful webservice using Asp.net WebAPI and used the windows authentication in the web.config file. This WebService is called by inhouse windows application in the internal network. Now the problem is when i send the request from 
the IE browser to the webService it authentication and authorization works fine. 
but when i send the request through the Widows application the user are not authenticated.
scenario :
   When i use below config, The Request from the webbrowser is authenticated correctly, But request from windows application are not authenticated even if users are in correct AD group with correct roles.

```
   <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
       <allow roles = "someGroup1"/>
       <allow roles = "Somegroup2"/>
       <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

what could be the problem please provide any suggestion.

Comment: You may need to confirm that the client application is running under the user context you expect. For example, if the request is made from a web service, the user account won't match the currently logged-in user.

Comment: would this be change in the code or a setting change in the windows application. I would really appreciate if you could provide me any details regarding that. Thank You

Comment: Usually neither one. It's possible for the code to impersonate different users, but most of the time it just has to do with the way the application is run. Windows Services and Web Services are usually run under system accounts. Normal winforms applications will usually run as the currently logged-in user.

Comment: Yes Windows Application is running as the currently logged in user.But why does the authentication works in the case of the IE browser and not for windows. Is there any way that i could log the user accessing the webservice through windows application and through the browser.

Comment: I found out the problem, The windows client was not sending the User Information to the Webhost so the authentication and Authorization was failing. Since I was using NTML Authentication, so to resolve this issue i had to add a Authenticator to the restClient as below:                                    client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the problem, The windows client was not sending the User Information to the Webhost so the authentication and Authorization was failing. Since I was using NTML Authentication, so to resolve this issue i had to add a Authenticator to the restClient as below:

```
var client = new RestClient();
     client.BaseUrl = ServiceUrl;
     client.RemoveHandler("application/json");
     client.RemoveHandler("text/json");
     **client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();**
```